# W3C DOM API in Java, get child elements by name

Tags: java, dom, w3c

I just realized that the method `Element.getElementsByTagName("someTagName")` returns a nodelist of all elements in the document that have a given tagname. What if I just want to get all child elements by tag name?

For example...

```
<person>
  <name>Bob</name>
  <car>
    <name>Toyota Corolla</name>
  </car>
</person>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` always operates in the context of element it is called on. If called on `Element`, only child elements by the given tag name would be accessed.
I think you are confusing this with `Document` object (org.w3c.dom.Document) `getElementsByTagName` method, then all elements by the given tag name in the document will be returned.

Comment: It's getElement**s**ByTagName.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not right -- this method returns descendant elements, so for example `getElementsByTagName("name")` executed on the `Element` representing person element will return 2 nodes.

Comment: @ArturNowak I don't follow. Which two does it return? The `node` that contains 'Bob' and 'Toyota Corolla'?

Comment: @Pureferret that's right -- two nodes: one with content 'Bob' and the other 'Toyota Corolla'

Comment: And the worst is that we could not rely on nodes order. The first node is not always be the "first direct child". If we have element "/person/name" after the element "/person/car", then "Toyota Corolla" will be the node at index(0)

Answer (score 31):

```
public static Element getDirectChild(Element parent, String name)
{
    for(Node child = parent.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling())
    {
        if(child instanceof Element && name.equals(child.getNodeName())) return (Element) child;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: In my case, I found it helpful to modify the if condition to also check the localName: if (child instanceof Element && 
                    (name.equals(child.getLocalName()) || name.equals(child.getNodeName()))) {

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem but none of the answers actually solved the question.

I was trying to query the operation Nodes INSIDE the portType Node of a WSDL, given that the binding node also have operations.

```
<portType name="MyService">
    <operation name="op1">
      <input wsam:Action="http://somedomain.org/MyService/MyServiceRequest" message="tns:MyServiceRequest"/>
      <output wsam:Action="http://somedomain.org/MyService/MyServiceResponse" message="tns:MyServiceResponse"/>
    </operation>
    ...
</portType>
<binding name="MyServicePortBinding" type="tns:MyService">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name="op1">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
```

Solved it by finding the parent (portTypes) and just casting it from Node to Element and using the method named above.

```
Node portType = document.getElementsByTagName("portType").item(0);
NodeList operations = ((Element)portType).getElementsByTagName("operation");
```

Which gave me as a result the operation elements INSIDE portType Node only.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. Try to look at the Node class instead:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getChildNodes()

There is a method called "getChildNodes" which returns the list of *all* direct child nodes. You then need to filter that list to only get the element-nodes with the right tagname.

Answer (score 0):

Not all elements in the document — all *descendant* elements of the element it's called on. It sounds like that's what you want. You just need to be calling it on the right `Element`. See [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29).